# Node Express throwing Error on form resubmission

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers

I am new to express. I am writing a demo authentication.

But it shows this error

```sh
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

when form re-submission happens. If i use a request logger than it shows that I get one post request. but the callback function on form.parse gets called twice. I just can't figure it out why is this happening.

```js
router.post('/signup', (req,res)=>{
    form.parse(req, (err, fld)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        let name = fld.name;
        let pass = fld.password;
        let checkUser = users.filter(item=>{ item.name == name })


        if(checkUser.length >0){
            res.render('form.html', {err: 'Username Exists!'});
            console.log('**') // this line prints twice when a from is resubmitted
        }else{

            let user = new User(name, pass);
           users.push(user);

            save(users, './user.json', ()=>{
                res.end('you can log in now');
            });
        }

    })
})
```

I am using ejs as view engine. 
*users is a array of user object.save is a function to write json files. they are just working fine.*

Comment: Could you explain step by step what happens? If I understand correctly, the first time the form is submitted, it works just fine. The second time, it breaks. Am I right? Are you using the same inputs each time?

Comment: yes, you got it right. First time it works fine, but if I reload the post request I mean resubmit the form this error shows up. I am using the same inputs every time, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer. The problem was with the creation of the formidable from obejct. What i did wrong was I created the form object at the beginning of the script. Which made the form object global and caused the trouble.

```js
let form = new formidale.IncomingForm()
```

I had to create new form form objects for each post request separately, that is I had to put this line inside the route.

```js
router.post('/signup', (req,res)=>{

    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm(); // this is where it should belong

    form.parse(req, (err, fld)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        let name = fld.name;
        let pass = fld.password;
        let checkUser = users.filter(item=>{ 
            return item.name == name            
        })


        if(checkUser.length >0){
            res.render('form.html', {'err': 'Username Exists!'});
            console.log('2');

            return
        }else{
            console.log(3);

            let user = new User(name, pass);
           users.push(user);

            save(users, './user.json', ()=>{
                res.end('you can log in now');
            });
        }

    })
})
```

Now it works fine.

I hope this answer to my own question helps someone out there sometime. :)